# Установка git в CentOS

Tags: linux, git, centos

Занимаюсь разработкой ПО. Понадобилось подключиться к общему репозиторию `git`. Выяснилось, что необходимые пакеты на компьютере не установлены. Достаточно ли просто установить в систему один пакет `git`?

```
$ sudo yum -y install git
```

Или для этого нужно что-то большее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В большинстве случаев для работы этого достаточно. Дополнительно можно поставить группу пакетов *«Средства разработки»*, которая включает в себя `git`, но скорее всего не последней версии:

```
$ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development tools"
```

Что входит в комплект:

```
$ yum group info "Development tools"
```

```
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│ Обязательные пакеты │ Пакеты по умолчанию │ Необязательные пакеты │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════════════════╡
│ autoconf            │ asciidoc            │ cmake                 │
│ automake            │ byacc               │ expect                │
│ binutils            │ ctags               │ rpmdevtools           │
│ bison               │ diffstat            │ rpmlint               │
│ flex                │ git                 │                       │
│ gcc                 │ intltool            │                       │
│ gcc-c++             │ jna                 │                       │
│ gdb                 │ ltrace              │                       │
│ glibc-devel         │ patchutils          │                       │
│ libtool             │ perl-Fedora-VSP     │                       │
│ make                │ perl-generators     │                       │
│ pkgconf             │ pesign              │                       │
│ pkgconf-m4          │ source-highlight    │                       │
│ pkgconf-pkg-config  │ systemtap           │                       │
│ redhat-rpm-config   │ valgrind            │                       │
│ rpm-build           │ valgrind-devel      │                       │
│ rpm-sign            │                     │                       │
│ strace              │                     │                       │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

---

***Если хочется поставить последнюю версию***: для `CentOS` `7` и `8`:

1. Устанавливаем группу пакетов *«Средства разработки»*

   ```
   $ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development tools"
   ```

   Полный набор вместе с *«Необязательными пакетами»*

   ```
   $ sudo yum -y groupinstall "Development tools" --with-optional
   ```
2. Удаляем стандартный пакет `git`

   ```
   $ sudo yum remove git
   ```
3. Добавляем дополнительные пакеты, которые понадобятся при сборке

   ```
   $ sudo yum -y install zlib-devel xmlto
   ```
4. Скачиваем актуальную версию, распаковываем: https://github.com/git/git
5. Сборка и установка (см. файл `INSTALL`)

   ```bsh
   $ make configure # as yourself
   $ ./configure    # as yourself
   $ make all doc   # as yourself
   $ make install install-doc install-html # as root
   ```

   Устанавливается оно в папку: `/usr/local/bin`. При необходимости добавляем эту папку в переменную `$PATH`.
6. Проверяем, что получилось

   ```bsh
   $ git --version # 2.27.0
   ```

---

Официальный сайт: https://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Установка с помощью yum**

Это простой и быстрый способ установки git на виртуальный сервер из стандартного репозитория CentOS. Стоит учесть, что в репозитории может быть не последняя версия git.

1. Обновляем пакеты операционной системы до актуальных версий:

   ```
   sudo yum update -y
   ```
2. Устанавливаем git:

   ```
   sudo yum install git -y
   ```
3. Проверяем установку командой:

   ```
   git --version
   ```